# Javascript Number input with text displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my website, I want a number input that includes a dollar sign after the number, i.e. when you type "30", it displays "30$" in the input field. The user should not be allowed to write any non-numeric characters, and it should behave like a "normal" text/number input field otherwise. (I don't need the spinner that comes with type="number" in an input field).

Is there anything like that, or is it not possible due to complexity? jQuery answers are welcome too.

Comment: Most common approach these days is for symbol to be outside input as text or icon.

Comment: Note that the `$` should often _preceed_ the field "$30" for USD, Australian AUD, Canadian CAD, but should _follow_ the field as you have for others such as Belize BZD, Brazil _Reals_ BRL — http://www.xe.com/symbols.php is a decent starting place for info, as is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following plugin to only allow the numeric values in your text input. As @charlietfl commented, the best practice is to use the sign outside of the input field.

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

This is the plugin. After you link it in your HTML file, in document.ready function in Jquery you just get your element and call numeric() method.

Comment: I decided to simply add labels to all of the input fields, in my case "Price (Dollars)". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery.inputmask library: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Here's an example jsfiddle:
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask